# Glade crashes when running "quickly design"

Tags: quickly, glade

When I run `quikly design` Glade opens and starts loading all my UI files. After a few seconds of loading each file it crashes silently (no error message or command line output). The Glade window is just gone. Running Glade normally doesn't result in a crash. Running it this way, however, without running `quickly design` I am obviously not able to graphically edit my application's GUI using Glade.

I have tried re-installing (and purging) quikly and all its dependancies with no luck. I have also tried creating a fresh blank new application (using the `quickly create ubuntu-application`command) with the same results - i.e. Glade crashes silently.

In addition I have tried my best at some Googling to resolve this problem, with no results.

I am running an updated Ubuntu 12.04 with Unity removed and KDE installed (from the kde backports PPA).

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: @JorgeCastro Apologies for that. I'll file a bug report forthwith. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.